# Which WhatsApp Business Account ID to use?

Tags: node.js, api, whatsapp

Can someone please clarify which is the correct WhatsApp Business Account ID to use to access the WhatsApp cloud API?

[image: whatsapp api sample]

I have properly set up my webhook and can receive messages. However when I try to send a message using the `WhatsApp Business Account ID` (marked as number 1 in the attached image) provided [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), I get the following error:

```
error: {
    message:
      "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '< my app id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    type: "GraphMethodException",
    code: 100,
    error_subcode: 33,
    fbtrace_id: "AQXqjuSJKTWBnyJdUK_W-jj",
},
```

However when I switch to the second `WhatsApp Business Account ID` in the curl command (marked as number 2 in the attached image), it works.

What confuses me is that the incoming message has the first `WhatsApp Business Account ID` (marked number 1 in the attached image) like so:

```
message: {
  object: "whatsapp_business_account",
  entry: [
    {
      id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  // This matches the first
      changes: [
          ...
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I am using the current api v14.0. Is there some setting I need to change?

Comment: the **Phone number ID** beside your marked no.1, and yes it is visible in send test message code as well where you have marked no 2. and i don't think you need any setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to add the user of this acces token to the WABA (Whatsapp Business Account). You can do it by accessing your **Business Manager > Whatsapp Accounts** menu.

If you don't know which user is this, you can paste the access token value on the [Access Token Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) to find out.

PS: it has to be done even for System Users!